# update record in mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a file name Musicians.js that contains:

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
 console.log("ID-->" + id);  //I GET CORRECT ID HERE

  var updates = req.body;
//It does not update any records
      Musician.update({"_id":id}, req.body, 
        function (err, numberAffected) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
          console.log('Updated %d musicians', numberAffected);  //gives 0 updated musicians
          return res.send(202);


      });
    };
```

In `routes.js`

```
app.put('/musicians/:id', musicians.update);
```

I call it like this:

```
$scope.updateTodo = function(id) {
        console.log("INSIDE UPDATE TO DO");
        console.log(id); 
        $scope.navMode = 'updateMusician';
        $scope.getOneTodo(id,function(data){
                var x=data;
                console.log("X" + x);
        $scope.formData.name= x.name;
        $scope.formData.band = x.band;
        $scope.formData.instrument = x.instrument;
        });
        $http.put('/musicians/' + id)
            .success(function(data) {
              $scope.todos = data;
                console.log("UPDATED||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||");
                      console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });


    };
```

I get 0 responses updated for it.

What could be wrong? Why does it not update records even for matching id's?

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```js
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  var Musician = req.musician;

  Musician = _extend(Musician, req.body);

  Musician.save(function (err, numberAffected) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log('Updated %d musicians', numberAffected);
      res.jsonp(Musician);
    });
};
```

if not then try changing this:

```js
var Musician = req.musician;
```

to this:

```js
var Musician = req.Musician;
```

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: @SimranKaur You have _id field. Type db.Musicians.find() in mongo and you'll see it. But have you tried my answer? Is there any errors?

Comment: Please check the updated question. Looks like I had a diferent problem all together.

Comment: @SimranKaur It looks to me that your not sending any data. According to documentation it needs to be: $http.put(url, data, [config]) where config is optional, but you only have $http.put(url). Try replacing this with $http.put(url, $scope.formData).